# Functions inside aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Question: why can't I call `sapply` inside `aes()`?

Goal of following figure: Create histogram showing proportion that died/lived so that the proportion for each combination of group/type sums to 1 (example inspired by previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200254/let-ggplot2-histogram-show-classwise-percentages-on-y-axis/31201910#31201910)).

I know you could make the figure by summarising outside of `ggplot` but the question is really about why the function isn't working inside of `aes`.

```
## Data
set.seed(999)
dat <- data.frame(group=factor(rep(1:2, 25)),
                  type=factor(sample(1:2, 50, rep=T)),
                  died=factor(sample(0:1, 50, rep=T)))

## Setup the figure
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=died, group=interaction(group, type), fill=group, alpha=type)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.5, 1)) +
  ylab("Proportion")

## Proportions, all groups/types together sum to 1 (not wanted)
p + geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)), position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

```
## Look at groups
stuff <- ggplot_build(p)
stuff$data[[1]]

## The long way works: proportions by group/type
p + geom_histogram(
    aes(y=c(..count..[..group..==1] / sum(..count..[..group..==1]),
            ..count..[..group..==2] / sum(..count..[..group..==2]),
            ..count..[..group..==3] / sum(..count..[..group..==3]),
            ..count..[..group..==4] / sum(..count..[..group..==4]))),
        position='dodge'
)
```

[image]

```
## Why can't I call sapply there?
p + geom_histogram(
    aes(y=sapply(unique(..group..), function(g)
        ..count..[..group..==g] / sum(..count..[..group..==g]))),
        position='dodge'
)
```

> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
>     object 'expr' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: sapply normally works in aes, as seen in this (dumb) example: `xy <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y=sapply(y,mean))) + geom_line()`. My guess is it is something to do with the scoping of the ..count.. and ..group.. by sapply, or the way the ..count.. and ..group.. are parsed inside the sapply function by aes, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, the issue arises because of a recursive call to `ggplot2:::strip_dots` for any aesthetics that include 'calculated aesthetics'. There is some discussion around the calculated aesthetics in [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502808/double-dots-in-a-ggplot). The relevant code in [layer.r](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/layer.r) is here:

```
new <- strip_dots(aesthetics[is_calculated_aes(aesthetics)])
```

i.e. `strip_dots` is called only if there are calculated aesthetics, defined using the regex `"\\.\\.([a-zA-z._]+)\\.\\."`.

`strip_dots` in takes a recursive approach, working down through the nested calls and stripping out the dots. The code is like this:

```
function (expr) 
{
    if (is.atomic(expr)) {
        expr
    }
    else if (is.name(expr)) {
        as.name(gsub(match_calculated_aes, "\\1", as.character(expr)))
    }
    else if (is.call(expr)) {
        expr[-1] <- lapply(expr[-1], strip_dots)
        expr
    }
    else if (is.pairlist(expr)) {
        as.pairlist(lapply(expr, expr))
    }
    else if (is.list(expr)) {
        lapply(expr, strip_dots)
    }
    else {
        stop("Unknown input:", class(expr)[1])
    }
}
```

If we supply an anonymous function this code as follows:

```
anon <- as.call(quote(function(g) mean(g)))
ggplot2:::strip_dots(anon)
```

we reproduce the error:

```
#Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
#  object 'expr' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Working through this, we can see that anon is a `call`. For `call`s, `strip_dots` will use `lapply` to call `strip_dots` on the second and third elements of the `call`. For an anonymous function like this, the second element is the `formals` of the function. If we look at the `formals` of `anon` using `dput(formals(eval(anon)))` or `dput(anon[[2]])` we see this:

```
#pairlist(g = )
```

For `pairlist`s, `strip_dots` tries to `lapply` it to itself. I'm not sure why this code is there, but certainly in this circumstance it leads to the error:

```
expr <- anon[[2]]
lapply(expr, expr)

# Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
#  object 'expr' of mode 'function' was not found
```

**TL; DR** At this stage, `ggplot2` doesn't support the use of anonymous functions within `aes` where a calculated aesthetic (such as `..count..`) is used.

Anyway, the desired end result can be achieved using `dplyr`; in general I think it makes for more readable code to separate out the data summarisation from the plotting:

```
newDat <- dat %>%
  group_by(died, type, group) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(type, group) %>%
  mutate(Proportion = count / sum(count))

p <- ggplot(newDat, aes(x = died, y = Proportion, group = interaction(group, type), fill=group, alpha=type)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.5, 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image: Final output]

#### ggplot2 fix

I've forked ggplot2 and have made two changes to aes_calculated.r which fix the problem. The first was to correct the handling of `pairlist`s to `lapply` `strip_dots` instead of `expr`, which I think must have been the intended behaviour. The second was that for formals with no default value (like in the examples provided here), `as.character(as.name(expr))` throws an error because `expr` is an empty name, and while this is a valid construct, it's not possible to create one from an empty string.

Forked version of ggplot2 at https://github.com/NikNakk/ggplot2 and pull request [just made](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1155).

Finally, after all that, the `sapply` example given doesn't work because it returns a 2 row by 4 column matrix rather than an 8 length vector. The corrected version is like this:

```
p + geom_histogram(
    aes(y=unlist(lapply(unique(..group..), function(g)
        ..count..[..group..==g] / sum(..count..[..group..==g])))),
    position='dodge'
)
```

This gives the same output as the `dplyr` solution above.

One other thing to note is that this `lapply` code assumes that the data at that stage is sorted by group. I think this is always the case, but if for whatever reason it weren't you would end up with the y data out of order. An alternative which preserves the order of the rows in the calculated data would be:

```
p + geom_histogram(
  aes(y={grp_total <- tapply(..count.., ..group.., sum);
  ..count.. / grp_total[as.character(..group..)]
  }),
  position='dodge'
)
```

It's also worth being aware that these expressions are evaluated in `baseenv()`, the namespace of the base package. This means that any functions from other packages, even standard ones like `stats` and `utils`, need to be used with the `::` operator (e.g. `stats::rnorm`).

Comment: I've fixed the problem in the ggplot2 source. Fork at https://github.com/NikNakk/ggplot2 . Pull request at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1155 . Issue at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1154

Answer (score 7):

After playing around a little, the problem appears to be using anonymous functions with ..group.. or ..count.. inside aes:

```
xy <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10) #data

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = sapply(y, mean))) + geom_line() #sapply is fine

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, group = y)) + 
       geom_bar(aes(y = sapply(..group.., mean))) #sapply with ..group.. is fine

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, group = y)) + 
       geom_bar(aes(y = sapply(..group.., function(g) {mean(g)})))
#broken, with same error

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, group = y)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = sapply(y, function(g) {mean(g)})), stat = "identity")
#sapply with anonymous functions works fine!
```

It seems like a really weird bug, unless I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: I've looked into this further and have pinned it down to how `ggplot2` handles calculated aesthetics (like `..group..`) with its `strip_plots` function. I thought at one point this would make a good comment to your answer, but as you can see with my answer, it ended up rather too long for that! Your initial investigative work was really handy in narrowing down the problem though.