# How to GET (not set) axis min and max from a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to get the xmin and xmax of an existing `ggplot`.
But `ggplot2` functions like `xlim()` only set this, they don't return the value from an existing plot.

Exploring the plot structure using `names(p)` and `str(p)` shows some candidate helpers (ggproto functions like get_scale() but unclear how these could be used.

Axis limits must be stored when they are set, but I can't see how to access them.

For ease of repro:

```
p = ggplot2::qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars)

# is it possible to access the xmin and xmax from p?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract data from a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378184/extract-data-from-a-ggplot)

Comment: You can do `ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_scales_x[[1]]$range$range`

Comment: Note that limits `ggplot_build(p)$layout$coord$limits` are NULL unless you set them.